# What does 'set -x' do in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, shell

I am learning from existing `Dockerfile`'s to start creating my own `Dockerfile`. I notice that most of the times, commands are started with either

```
RUN set -x ...
```

or

```
RUN set -ex; ...
```

Why does this do and why is this necessary? Is it necessary?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really a question about programming. Also, it seems that a research on the documentation should solve this doubt. Could you edit the question to tell us which documentation did you read, and also put some code that you have tried and which problem you have with it?

Comment: It's not a Docker thing, it's a shell thing. Works the same way in the RUN clause of a Dockerfile as in any other shell script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \`set -x\` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273665/what-does-set-x-do)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `-e` causes the command to stop on any errors. A more typical syntax is to separate commands with `&&` to stop on any error.

The `-x` causes the shell to output each command being run. This is useful for debugging scripts.

From the bash man page under `set`:

> -e      Exit immediately if a pipeline (which may consist of a
>   single simple command), a list,  or  a
>             compound  command  (see  SHELL GRAMMAR above),  exits with a non-zero status.  The shell does
>             not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a  while
>             or  until keyword, part of the test following the if or elif reserved words, part of any com‐
>             mand executed in a && or || list except the command following the final && or ||, any command
>             in  a pipeline but the last, or if the command's return value is being inverted with !.  If a
>             compound command other than a subshell returns a non-zero status  because  a  command  failed
>             while  -e  was  being  ignored,  the shell does not exit.  A trap on ERR, if set, is executed
>             before the shell exits.  This option applies to the shell environment and each subshell envi‐
>             ronment separately (see COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT above), and may cause subshells to exit
>             before executing all the commands in the subshell.
>
> If a compound command or shell function executes in a context where -e is being ignored, none
>   of the commands executed within the compound command or function body will be affected by the
>   -e setting, even if -e is set and a command returns a failure status.  If a compound  command
>   or shell function sets -e while executing in a context where -e is ignored, that setting will
>   not have any effect until the compound command or the command containing  the  function  call
>   completes.
>
> ...
>
> -x      After expanding each simple command, for command, case
>   command, select command, or arithmetic
>             for command, display the expanded value of PS4, followed by  the  command  and  its  expanded
>             arguments or associated word list.

Answer (score 1):

Set sets flags on the shell. So, basically this command says, before executing the following with the shell, make the shell exit on error (-e), and echo the command as it's run (-x).