# Hadoop fs command working on the command line but not in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, hdfs

I have a bash shell script that contains the following command:

```
hadoop fs -get ${WORKING_DIRECTORY}${OUTPUT_FILE}
```

which resolves into

```
hadoop fs -get /tmp/out.csv
```

When I run the shell script, this command produces no output, and the file is not transferred to the local instance. However, if I run the command `hadoop fs -get /tmp/out.csv` directly on the shell, it works.

What am I missing?

Comment: You are using wrong sigil `%`, insted of `$`

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. I am actually using `$`

Comment: Are you sure the env vars are available? Try to `echo` those on the script.

Comment: @HenryHarutyunyan I'm positive. They're defined only a few lines above and it's confirmed with `echo`s

Comment: @Cam mmhm is the path correct? Maybe an issue with the slash. Also, does the script have proper access rights to that csv file?

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be with your script not seeing environment variables such as `HADOOP_CONF`, and using local filesystem instead of HDFS.

Make sure that `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` are setup properly.

Also you should put `set -x`[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273665/what-does-set-x-do) on top of your script just to make sure the variables are resolved the way you think they should.

Prefer running your scripts in `strict mode` [1](http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/) at least when debugging, will save you a lot of time.